# Motherboard makes a buzzing noise and everything freezes

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, troubleshooting, nvidia-graphics-card

I am troubleshooting my home PC. It is failing, but I can't find source of the problem.

- mobo: Gigabyte GA-890GPA-UD3H (rev. 2.0)
- CPU: AMD Phenom II X6 Black Edition 1090T, 3616 MHz (18 x 201)
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460
- HDD: WDC WD5000AAKS-00UU3A0
- PSU: Thermaltake Evo Blue 550W
- RAM: Kingston 9905471-001.A00LF (2GB x 2)

The motherboard manual has no information about 1 loud and non-stopping buzzing noise (it sounds more like buzz then beep). It seems like an uncommon situation. Sound is coming from the motherboard speaker.

It makes this buzzing noise and everything just freezes during this noise. This noise may or may not randomly stop. If it stops then everything unfreezes and Windows continues to work normally.

1. Checked HDDs, replaced one because of too many bad sectors, but the second one seems fine. It has some bad sectors, but just 0.2%.
2. Tested some components with HeavyLoad and Furmark. Everything seems fine under a heavy resource load.

I can't simulate this loud buzzing noise behavior, it just happens randomly.

Sometimes the computer won't turn on after rebooting after that sound, POST is silent. I have to wait a bit before trying to turn it on again, then POST produces 1 short sound indicating all is fine and loads BIOS and the OS.

What should I try to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Where is the noise coming from? 'In the workings' or from speakers? It sounds very much like a classic overheat/under-power situation; but the qualifier would be that you have some sound source running when it happens & what you are actually hearing is a very short repeating burst of the last 0.01s of what was playing, over the speakers [too short to identify]

Comment: noise comming from motherboard speaker. Yes, seems like 0.01s repeated beep, but no such beep code in manual

Comment: Then investigate overheat/under-power. Strip & clean would be first thing to try; assuming you have no means to measure your PSU's output *under load* [which is not the same as not under load.

Answer (score 1):

My under informed opinion is that you have a power supply problem.  If you can find a PSU that is known working that would be my first stop. You might also try removing your video card and see if the same problem occurs.

At this stage you are likely in a remove as much as possible and then add back components until the problem reappears.

Answer (score 1):

Since your computer freezes and there is presence of bad sectors in your HDD(some manufactures do ship HDD with Bad sectors but still given the amount ) I would suggest you to run a diagnostics for OS corruptions.

Assuming that you are using WINDOWS and specifically WINDOWS 10:

1. Navigate to Command Prompt -> Right click and run as Administrator(very important) -> type `sfc/scannow`

This might take a few minutes to hours depending on your number of files present in your computer and will repair it.

2. If it gives errors saying "`Windows Resources detected some corrupt files but was unable to fix them`"  then type

   `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`

Wait for it to complete and if shows no errors then go advanced check by typing

```
`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`
```

after completion type

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

you can can directly go for `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
without going for `checkhealth` and `scanhealth`

Except for sfc the other commands require an INTERNET ACCESS to work

If you are using Ubuntu/Linux refer to
[how to run fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47953/can-i-run-fsck-or-e2fsck-when-linux-file-system-is-mounted)

Also as suggested by @berlin above try a replacement PSU unit and check if the problem occurs again since unregulated electricity flow through the system or PSU can cause such issues and can damage PSU and cause OS corruptions.